# Custom menu using linear layout issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a custom menu using linear layout for an android application. The scenario here is that I have created five menu tabs. I have to set the visibility of a menu or two to gone based on the navigation I will do. the problem is when I set the visibility of a menu tab to gone, the stretching of layout is shown explicitly. Please guide to get out of the problem

Answer (score 0):

You could use the visibility "Invisible" instead.
GONE: The view is totally removed from your layout.
INVISIBLE: The view isn't shown but it still uses the space it needs.

Comment: i think u did not get my question. I need the other views to use up the space when gone is set to a particular view.

Comment: So you may use "weight" attribute: if you set android:layout_weight="1" for each menu item, the whole space will be divided equally for each child. Is that what you need?

Comment: i have used the weight attribute. But the stretching of layout is seen explicitly in the app. Is there any way to avoid it.?

Comment: I think you're right, I don't get your problem. What's the current behavior and what behavior do you want instead?

Comment: I will put it clear. I have designed a layout with five views. I have to hide a layout based on the screen which i am navigating. Whenever i try to hide the views in the center , the other views stretch to use up the space present there. The stretching of layout is being shown which is not good to look at it. could you suggest me some options where the stretching of layout is not seen explicitly.